# Android restrict access to certain apps and website

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on an Online School app that requires restricting access to certain apps and websites during active class so that student doesn't get distracted. Once the class is over, the device can be used as a regular device.

We have implemented a similar feature on Windows (using browser extension and windows services) but we are not sure where to start in ReactNative/Android.

A few options I found online are **Parental Control** and **Android Enterprise** but that doesn't have options I am looking. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: React Native will be a bad choice for this. Any solution will need to be a lot of custom native code, you're going to be writing so many native modules that it will be an order of magnitude easier to just use Kotlin or Java

Comment: @GabeSechan I completely agree with you. I am currently doing POC. I was thinking of writing custom code and then exposing high-level API to React Native. But I am not sure where to start from. Do you know any android APIs which will allow me to restrict access to certain apps?

Comment: Android Enterprise is the only thing.  Device Policy Owner can work if you're aiming at old devices, but its deprecated and being removed (in favor of Android Enterprise).  Both of them pretty much require you to own the hardware-  it needs to be set up as the device owner, and nobody will let you do that to their personal device (it may not even be possible-  in the old days of device policy owner you could only have one owner and that was the Google app for anyone who set up a Google profile when they set up the device).